# How to get employee name with minimum and maximum of salary for second employee name with same salary value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a table odd_empcop in which minimum salary = 2000 and
maximum salary =8000 , there are many employees having maximum salary of 8000. I want to get the employee name with minimum salary and maximum salary of second employee.

I've applied this code:

```
(select emp_name, salary from odd_empcop
where salary = (select min(salary) from odd_empcop
                    order by salary ))
union
(select  emp_name, salary from odd_empcop
where salary = (select max(salary) from odd_empcop
    
                order by salary desc ));
```

getting output like:

```
emp_name salary
Gautham  2000
Melinda  8000
Cory     8000
Vikram   8000
```

But I want to get the output as:

```
emp_name salary
Gautham  2000
Cory     8000
```

I'VE GOT IT!!!!

```
(select emp_name, salary from odd_empcop
where salary = (select min(salary) from odd_empcop
                    order by salary ))
union
(select  emp_name, salary from odd_empcop
where salary = (select max(salary) from odd_empcop

                order by salary desc ) limit 1,1);
```

Comment: Why Cory in your desired output?

Comment: If you run your query different times does it change the order for `Melinda`, `Cory` and `Vikram` ?

Comment: @P.Salmon
it is not necessary to have cory as output, I want to get the second emp_name only,  not the first employee with salary 8000

Comment: @Ergest Basha, not it won't change

Comment: There is no first or second (or n) in your data -, data is not stored in any order in sql, you have to force order by including something which you can order by,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to get the details of the employee with the lowest salary and the second employee when ordered by descending salary and then by name:

```sql
SELECT emp_name,
       salary
FROM   (
  SELECT emp_name,
         salary,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC,  emp_name ASC) AS rn_min,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC, emp_name ASC) AS rn_max
  FROM   odd_empcop
) e
WHERE  rn_min = 1
OR     rn_max = 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE odd_empcop (
  salary NUMERIC(10,2),
  emp_name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO odd_empcop (emp_name, salary)
SELECT 'Gautham', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Melinda', 8000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cory',    8000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Vikram',  8000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | emp_name | salary |
> | --- | --- |
> | Melinda | 8000.00 |
> | Gautham | 2000.00 |

*[MySQL db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5644e3cf5d3907a20d2b543b89420f0d) [Oracle db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5644e3cf5d3907a20d2b543b89420f0d)*

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using LIMIT.

```
select emp_name, salary from odd_empcop where salary=(select max(salary) from odd_empcop order by salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1)
```

For example.

Answer (score -1):

I believe MYSQL supports a Limit clause (similar to SQLs TOP clause).  Maybe try something like
union
(select  emp_name, salary
from odd_empcop
where salary = (select max(salary) from odd_empcop
limit 1